# Recreate strrchr() but getting extra characters at the end of string

Tags: c

A task I have is to recreate the function strrchr. I figured out a way to iterate backward from the input given and stopping at the character I need to stop at, but the string came out backwards obviously. I already had created a function to reverse a string so I used that to reverse it back to normal. It works, but somewhere in my while loop when stopping at the character, it adds extra characters. Please help! I don't understand why!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include <stddef.h>
 
int
main () {
 
    char* my_strrchr(char* param_1, char param_2)
    {
        int i = strlen(param_1) - 1;
        int q = 0;
        char new[strlen(param_1)];
        char *new_ptr = new;
 
        while (i >= 0) {
            new[q] = param_1[i];
            printf("%c\n", new[q]);
            if (param_1[i] == param_2) {
                i = 0;
            }
            i--;
            q++;
        }
 
        int size = strlen(new_ptr) - 1;
 
        for (int i = 0, q = size; i < q; i++, q--) {
            char temp = new_ptr[i];
            new_ptr[i] = new_ptr[q];
            new_ptr[q] = temp;
        }
        printf("%s", new_ptr);
        return (char *)new_ptr;
 
    }
 
    char *phrase = "C Language is HARD.";
    char c = 'g';
 
    my_strrchr(phrase, c);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, it seems like you're trying to do too much for a simple `strrchr`. A simple way would be to have an iterator of the original string move in reverse till it finds `param_2`, and if it can't find then return `NULL`.

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of the original string. That's just making things more complicated than necessary. Set a pointer to the end of the string and move the pointer backwards be decrementing it until the character is found or the start of the string is reached.

Comment: What kaylum said is right. The way you are doing it now need a null terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: `return (char *)new_ptr;` That's very wrong as it is returning a pointer to a local variable. Local variables go out of scope (becomes invalid) when the function exits. It also doesn't satisfy the definition of `strrchr` which requires returning a pointer to somewhere in the original string.

Comment: Don't feel bad. Programming is actually really hard, and it takes a while to wrap your head around it. Even if this particular exercise was over your head just keep going and things will slowly begin to make sense. Good luck!

Comment: You've written your `my_strrchr()` function inside `main()`.  That is a non-standard extension of the language provided by GCC.   Don’t use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything fancy. Just walk the string from *the beginning*, updating a variable with the address of the character you're looking for every time it's found, and return it when you hit the end of the string (Unlike `strchr()`, where you return after the first match). That way you only need one pass through the string instead of the two times it takes if you first find the length and then go backwards.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Really should return a const char*. Silly standard. 
char *my_strrchr(const char *s, int c) {
  const char *pos = NULL;
  while (*s) {
    if ((unsigned char)*s == (unsigned char)c) pos = s;
    s++;
  }
  if (c == 0) {
    // If searching for '\0', return a pointer to the one
    // at the end of the string
    return (char *)s;
  } else {
    return (char *)pos;
  }
}

int main(void){
  const char *foo = "the quite wet duck quacks a lot";
  puts(my_strrchr(foo, 'q'));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to start from the end so that there are less iterations of the loop. Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vTcb3zWf1).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Shawn's implementation is more efficient than your linked code - `strlen` hides a full iteration over the string, so you're actually iterating over the string twice. Shawn's code just does it once.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein huh, that's true. Forgot about that :p (+1 from me then)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Like I mentioned in the answer, this only takes one pass. One that brings `strlen()` in has to do twice the work.