# EOF function proper usage in C

Tags: c, file-handling, eof

So the following is the code for reversing the inputted data in a file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  int i=0;
  char ch,str[10];
  FILE *ptr;
  ptr=fopen("input.txt","w");
  if(ptr==NULL){
    printf("File error\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
    putc(ch,ptr);
  }
  putc(' ',ptr);
  fclose(ptr);
  ptr=fopen("input.txt","r");
  while((ch=getc(ptr))!=EOF){
    str[i]=ch;
    i++;
    if(ch==' '){
      str[i]='\0';
      i=0;
      strrev(str);
      printf("%s",str);
    }
  }
}
```

This code reverses the data but prints the last word in a new line...For EOF I use "Enter"->"Ctrl+Z"->"Enter"...Is it the correct way?
I was expecting the data to be reversed in the same way as it was entered.
What the reason behind getting the last word in new line ? Please tell me the changes that i should make to get the desired output .

Comment: What is the content of the text file? Does it have line endings in it? If you read a string including the line ending and then reverse it what would happen? `char ch;` should be `int ch;`

Comment: @adabsurdum Text files should end in a new line, but they're not magically added.

Comment: @adabsurdum Maybe a particular editor will, but nothing at the OS level. In the case of Linux, it doesn't even have the *concept* of a text file being handled differently from a binary one in the internals. That's a Windows distinction. (Plus using Ctrl-Z for EOF instead of Ctrl-D suggests Windows anyways, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't magically add a newline either, just convert between CRLF and LF)

Comment: @Shawn -- well, I can't make it happen in a test program now. I've had magically appearing newlines appended to the end of POSIX .txt files in the past, but now I'm not sure what caused it; probably an editor trick as you suggest.

Comment: @Shawn not only Windows but also on other OSes that don't use `\n` like classic mac

Comment: ch must be int [Why the return type of getchar() is int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60332668/995714)

Answer (score 2):

If `xyz` is the last word you enter before signalling EOF by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the last part of the file is going to be `xyz<newline><space>`. Since you reverse what's in your read buffer when you hit a space, what's printed out for the last word is `<space><newline>zyx`.

One possible fix: Treat newlines and spaces as word breaks, not just space (Maybe anything that makes [`isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) return true). I would also print the whitespace character *after* the reversed word instead of including it as part of the text to reverse (Which would also address your issue). Including fixing the issue that [`ch` should be an `int`, not a `char`](https://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html), and a few other tweaks but **not** fixing the issue that any word longer than 9 characters will cause your program to write past the end of the `str` array, it might look something like:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef WIN32
// _strrev() (strrev() is a deprecated alias) is a Windows-specific
// function.  Quick and dirty implementation for other systems.
char *_strrev(char *s) {
  char *start = s;
  char *end = strchr(s, '\0');
  if (s == end) {  // Empty string
    return start;
  }
  end -= 1;
  while (s != end) {
    char temp = *end;
    *end = *s;
    *s = temp;
    s += 1;
    end -= 1;
  }
  return start;
}
#endif

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  int ch;
  char str[10];
  FILE *ptr;
  ptr = fopen("input.txt", "w");
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("File error\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putc(ch, ptr);
  }
  putc(' ', ptr);
  fclose(ptr);
  ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  while ((ch = getc(ptr)) != EOF) {
    if (isspace(ch)) {
      if (i > 0) { // Skip empty words (Caused by multiple spaces in a row)
        char delim = ch;
        str[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        _strrev(str);
        printf("%s%c", str, delim);
      }
    } else {
      str[i++] = ch;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How do you think `strrchr()` finds the end of the string?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it has to first find the trailing nul by looking at every preceding character. Remember, C strings don't track their own length.

Comment: See for example my `strrchr()` implemention from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69204102/9952196). There's no advantage to using it over `strchr()` here.

Comment: I stand corrected, [glibc strrchr()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strrchr.c;h=3c6e715d3b4b9759e2b13d7cd98248131c6ac11a;hb=refs/heads/release/2.37/master) does iterate forward -- you wouldn't save anything there. Old dog relearns old trick.